# tailwind background img not showing

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Might be a simple fix but I am wondering why my background-image for my hero section isn't showing?

according to the documentation, applying w-full and h-full with bg-cover will at least show the image. The only solution to this would be to add a position: absolute class to it. I am wondering why that is? The documentation does not say to add an absolute class but that seemed to solve it but I would like to know why (its confusing the heck out of me lol)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/tailwind.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>



    <div class=" w-full h-full" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624542316074-5ce16f7b6d41?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80');">
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give the `div` some `height` with some content like text or use the tailwind utility `h-{something}` dont use `h-full` as it is the same to css `height: 100%;` if you want it to fill the screen use the utility class `h-screen` see the snippet below

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="w-full h-screen" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624542316074-5ce16f7b6d41?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80');">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel like the documentation wasn't too clear and i guess personally i need to brush up on CSS basics first =D.. totally forgot about the whole viewport Height thing..